# Passing errors coming from the API call

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

I am using 2 separate `liveData` exposed to show the error coming from the API. I am basically checking if there is an exception with the API call, pass a failure status and `serverErrorLiveData` will be observed.

So I have `serverErrorLiveData` for error and `creditReportLiveData` for result without an error.

I think I am not doing this the right way. Could you please guide me on what is the right way of catching error from the API call. Also, any concerns/recommendation on passing data from repository on to view model.

What is the right way of handing loading state?

CreditScoreFragment

```
    private fun initViewModel() {
    viewModel.getCreditReportObserver().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer<CreditReport> {
        showScoreUI(true)
        binding.score.text = it.creditReportInfo.score.toString()
        binding.maxScoreValue.text = "out of ${it.creditReportInfo.maxScoreValue}"
        initDonutView(
            it.creditReportInfo.score.toFloat(),
            it.creditReportInfo.maxScoreValue.toFloat()
        )
    })
    viewModel.getServerErrorLiveDataObserver().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer<Boolean> {
        if (it) {
            showScoreUI(false)
            showToastMessage()
        }
    })
    viewModel.getCreditReport()
}
```

MainActivityViewModel

```
    class MainActivityViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val dataRepository: DataRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    var creditReportLiveData: MutableLiveData<CreditReport>
    var serverErrorLiveData: MutableLiveData<Boolean>

    init {
        creditReportLiveData = MutableLiveData()
        serverErrorLiveData = MutableLiveData()
    }

    fun getCreditReportObserver(): MutableLiveData<CreditReport> {
        return creditReportLiveData
    }

    fun getServerErrorLiveDataObserver(): MutableLiveData<Boolean> {
        return serverErrorLiveData
    }

    fun getCreditReport() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val response = dataRepository.getCreditReport()

            when(response.status) {
                CreditReportResponse.Status.SUCCESS -> creditReportLiveData.postValue(response.creditReport)
                CreditReportResponse.Status.FAILURE -> serverErrorLiveData.postValue(true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

DataRepository

```
class DataRepository @Inject constructor(
        private val apiServiceInterface: ApiServiceInterface
) {

    suspend fun getCreditReport(): CreditReportResponse {
        return try {
            val creditReport = apiServiceInterface.getDataFromApi()
            CreditReportResponse(creditReport, CreditReportResponse.Status.SUCCESS)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            CreditReportResponse(null, CreditReportResponse.Status.FAILURE)
        }
    }
}
```

ApiServiceInterface

```
interface ApiServiceInterface {
    @GET("endpoint.json")
    suspend fun getDataFromApi(): CreditReport
}
```

CreditScoreResponse

```
data class CreditReportResponse constructor(val creditReport: CreditReport?, val status: Status) {
    enum class Status {
        SUCCESS, FAILURE
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's creates complexity and increased chances for a coding error to have two LiveData channels for success and failure. You should have a single LiveData that can offer up the data or an error so you know it's coming in orderly and you can observe it in one place. Then if you add a retry policy, for example, you won't risk somehow showing an error after a valid value comes in. Kotlin can facilitate this in a type-safe way using a sealed class. But you're already using a wrapper class for success and failure. I think you can go to the source and simplify it. You can even just use Kotlin's own Result class.

(Side note, your `getCreditReportObserver()` and `getServerErrorLiveDataObserver()` functions are entirely redundant because they simply return the same thing as a property. You don't need getter functions in Kotlin because properties basically are getter functions, with the exception of suspend getter functions because Kotlin doesn't support `suspend` properties.)

So, to do this, eliminate your CreditReportResponse class. Change your repo function to:

```
suspend fun getCreditReport(): Result<CreditReport> = runCatching {
    apiServiceInterface.getDataFromApi()
}
```

If you must use LiveData (I think it's simpler not to for a single retrieved value, see below), your ViewModel can look like:

```
class MainActivityViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val dataRepository: DataRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    val _creditReportLiveData = MutableLiveData<Result<CreditReport>>()
    val creditReportLiveData: LiveData<Result<CreditReport>> = _creditReportLiveData 

    fun fetchCreditReport() { // I changed the name because "get" implies a return value
    // but personally I would change this to an init block so it just starts automatically
    // without the Fragment having to manually call it.
        viewModelScope.launch { // no need to specify dispatcher to call suspend function
            _creditReportLiveData.value = dataRepository.getCreditReport()
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your fragment:

```
private fun initViewModel() {
    viewModel.creditReportLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { result -> 
        result.onSuccess {
            showScoreUI(true)
            binding.score.text = it.creditReportInfo.score.toString()
            binding.maxScoreValue.text = "out of ${it.creditReportInfo.maxScoreValue}"
            initDonutView(
                it.creditReportInfo.score.toFloat(),
                it.creditReportInfo.maxScoreValue.toFloat()
            )
        }.onFailure {
            showScoreUI(false)
            showToastMessage()
        }
    viewModel.fetchCreditReport()
}
```

*Edit: the below would simplify your current code, but closes you off from being able to easily add a retry policy on failure. It might make better sense to keep the LiveData.*

Since you are only retrieving a single value, it would be more concise to expose a suspend function instead of LiveData. You can privately use a Deferred so the fetch doesn't have to be repeated if the screen rotates (the result will still arrive and be cached in the ViewModel). So I would do:

```
class MainActivityViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val dataRepository: DataRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    private creditReportDeferred = viewModelScope.async { dataRepository.getCreditReport() }

    suspend fun getCreditReport() = creditReportDeferred.await()
}

// In fragment:
private fun initViewModel() = lifecycleScope.launch {
    viewModel.getCreditReport()
        .onSuccess {
            showScoreUI(true)
            binding.score.text = it.creditReportInfo.score.toString()
            binding.maxScoreValue.text = "out of ${it.creditReportInfo.maxScoreValue}"
            initDonutView(
                it.creditReportInfo.score.toFloat(),
                it.creditReportInfo.maxScoreValue.toFloat()
            )
        }.onFailure {
            showScoreUI(false)
            showToastMessage()
        }
}
```

Comment: thank you so so soo much for the detailed explanation and suggestions, that is very very helpful and great corrections.

Comment: )4, thank you for you response, when I try this in the repository I get `'kotlin.Result' cannot be used as a return type`

Comment: sorry resolved it I had to add `freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xallow-result-return-type"]` in Gradle
` kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xallow-result-return-type"]
    }`

Comment: Make sure you update to the latest Kotlin version (1.5.2 currently). Then you don't have to fool with the kotlinOptions. That was a restriction that they had in versions before 1.5.